# SQL using where like "%ads%" + CASE WHEN

Tags: sql

My query is

```
SELECT Abonent FROM phone
WHERE `Street` LIKE "%примiська%" AND WHERE
CASE WHEN `House` % 2 = 0 THEN 'Правий'
ELSE 'Лiвий'
END AS Side
```

And I get

[image]

How can I do that `case` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve and what the issue is ? Please rephrase your question as right now it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `where` is definitely incorrect; it seems you want `case` in `select`: you filter `Abonent` being on required `Street`(s) and add a computed field to `select` showing on which side of a street (left or right) each abonent is.

```
select Abonent,
       case
         when `House` % 2 = 0 then 'Правий'
         else 'Лiвий' 
       end as Side 
  from phone
 where `Street` like '%примiська%'
```